# Elasticsearch Infraestructure

Tags: security, elasticsearch, cloud, elastic-stack, antivirus

people.

My company and I wishes to use Elasticsearch for SIEM and possible XDR for our costumers -- we want to substitute Zabbix.

But We can´t go on with the project because of the numerous questions about the infrastructure -- planning to build it with a cloud provider like AWS (or a cheaper one for us Brazilians xD). Knowing that we are a MSP with a multi-tenant environment, can someone help us to understand some things?

1- How many nodes should we have? -- thinking about high availability and fail proof. We do the "hot" "warm" with 3 nodes each instance?

2- How many hosts can each instance support? Do you have numbers like: a machine with 4vCPUs, 8Gib RAM can hold 100 hosts in an environment.

3- How about storage consumption? Can you give us an estimation of how many storage we need for a specific number of devices?

Comment: It will be entirely depends on how much data you are going to store and other factors. I will say just do the google “ElasticSearch capacity planning” and you will get lot of blogs and documentation.

Comment: they are great but pretty much says: "you need to know your data throughtput" and unfurtunatly we dont have an estimate about that. It will be a pain to know certainlly how many logs a Sophos firewall or a Kaspersky Security Center, in a certain environmet, can generate. 

And for testing it will be a pain too, because we dont have the infraestructure.

Comment: In this scenario, if someone suggest then it will going to either under-utilised or over-utilised. I will suggest to have single node and the index data for 1 or 2 days and check all the scenarios and based on that create estimates and go with it.

Comment: thanks man, i will probably do that.